# loss of depth buffer accuracy on iOS

Tags: metal, depth-buffer

I'm doing depth peeling with a very simple fragment function:

```
struct VertexOut {
    float4 position  [[ position ]];
};

fragment void depthPeelFragment(VertexOut in [[ stage_in ]],
                                depth2d<float, access::read> previousDepth)
{
    float4 p = in.position;
    if(!is_null_texture(previousDepth) && p.z <= previousDepth.read(uint2(p.xy)))
    {
        discard_fragment();
    }
}
```

(My depth buffer pixel format is `MTLPixelFormatDepth32Float`)

This works well on my Mac. In each pass I submit the same geometry, and eventually no more fragments are written and the process terminates. For example, with a test sphere, there are two passes with the same number of fragments written each pass (front and back hemispheres).

However on iPad, the process does not terminate. There are some (not all) fragments which, despite being rendered in the previous pass, are not discarded in subsequent passes.

**What platform differences could cause this?**

**Is the z-coordinate of the position attribute always the value written to the depth buffer?**

According to Apple engineer, it's not a logarithmic depth buffer.

Note that I cannot simply limit the number of passes (I'm not using this for OIT).

**Update:**

Here's what the depth texture looks like on the 3rd pass via GPU capture (the green represents the bounds of rendered geometry):

[image: Depth texture for test sphere]

The distribution of points makes this look like a floating point accuracy issue.

Furthermore, if I add an epsilon to the previous depth buffer:

```
p.z <= previousDepth.read(uint2(p.xy))+.0000001
```

then the process does terminate on the iPad. However the results aren't accurate enough for downstream use.

Comment: How are you determining when "no more fragments are written"? I guess a visibility result buffer and mode. If you're using `MTLVisibilityResultModeCounting`, it may not be available on all feature sets. Otherwise, can you use Xcode's graphics debugger to see what's going on? You may need to temporarily limit the number of passes just to make sure your frame ends for the capture, but it should still be informative to examine the last draws. Also, be sure to enable API validation.

Comment: @KenThomases I'm counting the number of pixels that are closer than the clear depth of 1.0 after the command buffer finishes. I'm not using an occlusion query.

Comment: Have you considered outputting the depth explicitly? Make the return type of the fragment shader a struct containing a field with the `[[depth(less)]]` attribute, and set that to `p.z` if the fragment isn't discarded.